# What is the use of thread-id in android sms app

Tags: android

I want to make SMS app in android but i did not understand what is thread id in sms. Can you please explain what is thread id and what is it used in retrieving of sms?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

`thread id` is for your messages (more like conversation). for example you have messages from your bank like credited ,debited sms come under one thread.

Answer (score 1):

Thread id is basically a conversation id. It is assigned for a conservation (can be a group chat or one to one). When there is some change (like adding/removing a person to group chat, etc.) in group chat the conservation will be assigned with new thread id. When restoring sms the thread id is used to add to an existing conversation.